# Проблема с добавлением данных в таблицы

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, foreign-key

Начинаю работу с базами данных, не хейтите сильно. Создал базу данных, таблицы, связан их через sqlyog(по заданию лабы так надо). Теперь при добавлении данных в таблицы, возникает ошибка:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lab33`.`задания`, CONSTRAINT `@n0@g0@k0@g0@t0@o0@r1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idЗадания`) REFERENCES `сотрудники` (`idСотрудники`)). Вижу что ошибка идиотская, скорее всего, но гугл мне не особо помог в решении...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вам написало, что вы пытаетесь в поле связи вставить несуществующее значение в связанной таблице

Comment: Не совсем понимаю данного ответа, почему у меня что-то не существует, если вообще таблицы еще пустые. Типы данных у связанных столбцов одинаковые, я все еще не понимаю проблемы, можно, пожалуйста, максимально тупой ответ, насколько это возможно, потому что мне сложно пока, только первые работы по БД